# How to add another field in this javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script and I am trying to create a third value (m3) but I do not know what to do with the `obj.nodeValue=(obj.nodeValue==m1)?m2:m1;` line.
Also how would I go about putting html in m1, m2 and m3? specifically the bold tag.
Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function adMessage() {

   delay=10000;

   m1='Place your Thanksgiving orders today!';
   m2='All orders must be received by November 20th!';
   m3='testing';
   obj=document.getElementById('orders').firstChild;

   obj.nodeValue=(obj.nodeValue==m1)?m2:m1;

   setTimeout(function(){adMessage()},delay);
 }
if(window.addEventListener){
   window.addEventListener('load',adMessage,false);
 }
else { 
if(window.attachEvent){
   window.attachEvent('onload',adMessage);
  }
 }
</script>


<p id="orders">Place your Thanksgiving orders today!</p>
```

Comment: When do you want to add 3d string? What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
obj.nodeValue=(obj.nodeValue==m1)?m2:m1;
```

is a short version of this

```
if (obj.nodeValue == m1) 
{
    obj.nodeValue = m2;
} 
else 
{
  obj.nodeValue = m1;
}
```

Depending on your logic to display the m3 value you need to extend this decision.

If you want to switch to the next message at each interval then maybe this is your solution:

```
if (obj.nodeValue == m1) 
{
    obj.nodeValue = m2;
} 
else if (obj.nodeValue == m2) 
{
  obj.nodeValue = m3;
}
else 
{
   obj.nodeValue = m1;
}
```

And the idea of Felix is of course better. If you put your messages in an array you can easily extend it.

For your part of the question about embedding HTML tags: you need to set innerHTML value of the element instead of nodeValue.

I put up a running jsfiddle with all aspects of your question: http://jsfiddle.net/eNape/1/

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a binary case anymore, you cannot compare the current value and decide based on that which message to show (well, ok, you can, but it gets ugly).

A clean way would be to create a list of messages, keep track of the index of the current message and advance the index (with wrap around).

Example:

```
var index = 0;
var messages = [
    'Place your Thanksgiving orders today!',
    'All orders must be received by November 20th!',
    'testing'
];
var delay = 10000;

function adMessage() {
   var node = document.getElementById('orders').firstChild;

   node.nodeValue = messages[index];
    // advance index and wrap around if necessary
   index = (index + 1) % messages.length;

   setTimeout(adMessage, delay);
}
```

With proper placement of your code, you don't need to listen to the `load` event and can avoid searching the DOM node inside the function over and over again.